# Monospaced Font w/out Syntax Highlighting in Github Flavored Markdown

Tags: github, syntax-highlighting, plaintext, monospace

The title pretty much says it all: I'd like to write a paragraph in `monospaced` font using GFM, but without any programming language's syntax highlighting. I'd think it would be

````
```txt
````

or

````
```text
````

or maybe nothing:

````
```
````

But no luck. Is this even possible with GFM?

Comment: Better for either [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) (since it has nothing to do with coding) or direct to GitHub:Support

Comment: This also doesn't work in gitter ... awful when trying to paste compiler messages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try indenting with four spaces (i.e. a normal markdown code block) rather than using a fenced code block. This worked for me in GitLab. In GitHub just ``` worked.

Comment: It appears to be working, now... Not sure what was happening.

Comment: Sure would have been nice if they (Github) hadn't borked the tt tag. :(